# Programatically insert text into command that normally blocks event loop

Tags: emacs, event-loop, icicles

I'd like to implement a command that types the first few characters into an existing command and lets me type the rest.

For example, a variant of `icicle-execute-extended-command` that starts with "icicle-" already entered.

I have tried:

- keyboard macros

  - fail (even on simple things like `M-x i c i c l e s`) for no apparent reason.
- functions

  - calling `icicle-execute-extended-command` block the command sequence

How would I go about doing this in a generalized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question.
Here's something generic you can try:

```
(defun no-mondays ()
  (interactive)
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    (lambda()
      (insert "monday"))
    (call-interactively 'query-replace)))
```

And here's a refactoring:

```
(defun with-initial-minibuffer (str fun)
  `(lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
         (lambda ()
            (insert ,str))
       (call-interactively ',fun))))

(defalias 'no-weekends
    (with-initial-minibuffer
        "\\(?:satur\\|sun\\)day"
      'query-replace-regexp))
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work perfectly, I can even launch macros and commands in the minibuffer before starting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `completing-read` yourself in your command definition, then just pass the text to insert as the `INITIAL-INPUT` argument. That's what it's for.

If you use `icicle-define-command` or `icicle-define-file-command` (so that your command will be a [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands#multi-command)), then same thing: pass the `INITIAL-INPUT` arg.

If you use such a macro, be sure to put something like this in the file that defines the command, so the macro definition is available a byte-compilation time:

```
 (eval-when-compile
  (or (condition-case nil
          (load-library "icicles-mac")   ; Use load-library to ensure latest .elc.
        (error nil))
      (require 'icicles-mac)))
```